# Remote Server Issue-Distributed Testing

Tags: jmeter, remote-server, jmeter-4.0, distributed-testing

I have a Master machine(192.xxx.x.xx) and Two Slave Machine(192.xxx.x.xx,192.xxx.x.xx).

In the Master Machine jmeter properties file , i added the two salve machine IP.
I run the server.bat file in the Slave Machine respectively.

But one of my slave machine showed an error of **Port 1099 Busy**.So i changed the port of that particular Salve Machine to **1098** and rerun the server.bat file.

Now when i select **Remote Start ALL** command in the Master Machine,the Slave Machine in which the port was changed does not execute the Test. But the other slave machine whose port is 1099 successfully executed the test.

Can anybody tell me the exact issue with the other slave machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow [changing RMI port steps](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#portchange):

> JMeter uses the standard RMI port 1099. It is possible to change this. For this to work successfully, all the following need to agree:
>
> - On the server, start rmiregistry using the new port number
> - On the server, start JMeter with the property server_port defined
> - On the client, update the remote_hosts property to include the new remote host:port settings
>
> Since JMeter 2.1.1, the jmeter-server scripts provide support for changing the port. For example, assume you want to use port 1664 (perhaps 1099 is already used).
>
> On Windows (in a DOS box)
>
> ```
> C:\JMETER> SET SERVER_PORT=1664
> C:\JMETER> JMETER-SERVER [other options]
> ```
>
> On Unix:
>
> ```
> $ SERVER_PORT=1664 jmeter-server [other options]
> ```
>
> [N.B. use upper case for the environment variable]
>   In both cases, the script starts rmiregistry on the specified port, and then starts JMeter in server mode, having defined the "server_port" property.
>
> The chosen port will be logged in the server jmeter.log file (rmiregistry does not create a log file).